# clear data and then load data

Tags: sql-loader, controlfile

I'm ruuning below script to insert data from .csv file to oracle table A. How I can update code to clear data of table A first and then insert data using one file.

```sql
load data
append
INTO TABLE USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
(AS_OF_DATE "TO_DATE(:AS_OF_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')"
,MOODY,S_AND_P,FITCH,DBRS,RISK_RATING,BAS_RISK_RATING)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "APPEND" use "TRUNCATE".  Back up first before testing!

Comment: So new script will be like  load data Truncate INTO TABLE USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN fields ... This will clear the table how it'll insert new records into table. I want to achieve both the task i.e. clearing previous table records and inserting new records in empty table